# Some input files use or override a deprecated API Flutter build android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging, flutter

I have a flutter project and I want to build it in android studio. I build it with this command in the terminal:

`flutter build apk --release`

I'm getting this error report:

```
Note: C:\Users\Jovik\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-1.5.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\pathprovider\PathProviderPlugin.java uses or overrides
 a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint: deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint: deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint: unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint: unchecked for details.
C:\Users\Jovik\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\SharedPreferencesPlugin.java:25: warn
ing: [deprecation] getFlutterEngine() in FlutterPluginBinding has been deprecated
    setupChannel(binding.getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor(), binding.getApplicationContext());
```

I'm not a flutter developer so I have no special knowledge of these technologies. I have upgraded flutter and the flutter doctor did not find any error what problem? Could you help me too? Give advice on what I’m doing wrong.

Comment: This is warning not an error, you can continue or try to fix it by yourself, by pulling the shared preference to your machine

Comment: try this:
add below code in Android/app/build.gradle file

configurations {
compile.exclude group: 'com.google.zxing'
}

Answer (score 7):

This is a known issue with the shared_preferences plugin with flutter. This issue has been addressed about [20 days ago](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/2536). Make sure that you are using the newest version of [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences#-analysis-tab-) (0.5.6+3) and update to reflect this in your pubspec.yaml.

Comment: Yeah you are right.In my case it was 0.5.6.I updated it to 0.5.6+3 and typed in terminal flutter pub get then rebuilded it but i'm still getting this error.What do you advice?

Comment: Try running `flutter clean` and then also running `flutter upgrade`.

Comment: At the time of this writing, flutter firebase messaging has the same problem. I am using the latest version. Conclusion: ignore the warning message. It is the responsibility of the flutter library's programmer, not us.

Comment: It's not so really clever to mention "20 days ago" in a comment like this...